# CUDA cudaMemcpu Segmentation fault when copying array of object pointers

Tags: c++, c, cuda, segmentation-fault

I am trying to move an array of pointers to the device, where each pointer is pointing to a class object. However, I get a Segmentation fault at the line using cudaMemcpy. I am trying to follow the lines used in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096660/cudamemcpy-array-of-pointers-where-each-pointer-points-to-an-array).

main.cu

```
#include "testclass.cuh"
#include <iostream>


__global__ void printtest(Test* test){
    printf("HELLO FROM CUDA\n");
    printf("CUDA1 : %i\n", test->hello);
    Test test2(6);
    printf("CUDA2 : %i\n", test2.hello);
    printf("BYEEE FROM CUDA\n");

}

int main(){
    printf("hello\n");
    Test* test = new Test(512);
    printf("CPU : %i\n", test->hello);
    Test* devtest;
    cudaMalloc(&devtest, sizeof(Test));
    cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(devtest, test, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {                                   
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",             
            cudaGetErrorString(err), __LINE__-3, __FILE__);
    }
    printtest<<<1, 1>>>(devtest);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();



    printf("hello2\n");
    Test** test3 = new Test*[2];
    test3[0] = new Test(12299);
    test3[1] = new Test(234923);
    printf("CPU : %i\n", test3[0]->hello);
    Test** devtest3;
    cudaMalloc(&devtest3, 2*sizeof(Test*));
    printf("CPU2\n");
    err = cudaMemcpy(devtest3[0], test3[0], sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {                                   
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",             
            cudaGetErrorString(err), __LINE__-3, __FILE__);
    }
    printf("CPU3\n");
    printtest<<<1, 1>>>(devtest3[0]);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

testclass.cu

```
#include "testclass.cuh"

__host__ __device__ Test::Test(int in){
    hello = in;
}
```

testclass.cuh

```
class Test {
public: 
    int hello;
    __host__ __device__ Test(int);
};
```

Comment: `devtest3[0]` is an uninitialized pointer, so you can't copy anything there. You need to allocate space for the `Test` objects, too, not just the pointers.

Comment: I see, thank you. I fixed the above by changing `Test** devtest3;` to `Test* devtest[2];` and then mallocing `cudaMalloc(&devtest3[0], sizeof(Test));`. instead of `cudaMalloc(&devtest3, 2*sizeof(Test*));`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using @molbdnilo 's comment.

main.cu

```
...
printf("hello2\n");
    Test** test3 = new Test*[2];
    test3[0] = new Test(12299);
    test3[1] = new Test(234923);
    printf("CPU : %i\n", test3[0]->hello);
    Test* devtest3[2];
    cudaMalloc(&devtest3[0], sizeof(Test));
    printf("CPU2\n");
    err = cudaMemcpy(devtest3[0], test3[0], sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {                                   
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",             
            cudaGetErrorString(err), __LINE__-3, __FILE__);
    }
    printf("CPU3\n");
    printtest<<<1, 1>>>(devtest3[0]);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
...
```